# How to pass values between two independent winform applications each on different machines in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, network-programming

***I have two winform applications coded in C# each on different applications.
And now I want to pass values between them**..*It can be done easily in case of websites but how to do that in winform appications.

**Please Remember these forms are not parent and child forms of the same applications.But they are forms of two different applications.**

**Logic**:Actually,I will be doing some validation on 1 machine based on encounterId. And if the encounter Id is validated,Then I want to run an exe(programed in C# my me only) on different machine.(i.e. I plan to send that validated encounter ID on 2nd machine and open the exe with the person details related with that validated encounter)

Comment: is one application started from the other? Or are they two completely independent applications?

Comment: No,They are both independent applications and that too on different machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using WCF or one of the underlying technologies like .NET Remoting.

Comment: ... and the UI library (winforms, wpf, etc.) is really irrelevant.